# Magento post from controller

Tags: forms, magento, post, controller

Lately I've been using `cURL` to post data back from a custom Magento controller to a custom page on the same website.

However, the way I do it somehow breaks Magento's log in data. So I've tried another way. Magento has `cURL` functionality built into it (`Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl`).

I've tried to Post through this, but so far it has been over my head and documentation on the web is fairly sparse. I need help with this. I've got a string with all the `$_POST` data ready to go. Please can someone tell me how to send it?

This:

```
$url="<URL>";
$curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl;
$curl->setConfig(array('timeout' => 15));
$curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST,$url, '1.1', array(), $poststring);
$result = $curl->read();
$curl->close();
```

...isn't sending data .

Edit:

I've tried the non-Magento cURL, but didn't know about session Data. I still have no Idea how to send session data, either.
Now, I've tried session variables, but the result is that I can set and extract data on one page, but when changing pages the data is lost. So, this can't be used currently between the controller and view.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, because they other ways to accomplish it? Is the 'custom page' within magento or on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

better you can use the magento sessions

http://magento-rohan.blogspot.in/2012/03/magento-get-set-unset-session.html

here is this how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us more information about what are you trying to achieve. Basically you need to tell us where are you sending POST request to? Perhaps another Magento instance or even same Magento website? Are you expecting user to have same session it is having now? Once you give us more info I will edit my answer. For now I will try to guess what is bothering you based on the input you gave.

When you are submitting POST request with curl from server side, that means that user is no longer interacting with the "page" you are trying to submit post request to.

If user is not interacting with it, that means it is not sending user session information.

Basically it looks like this:

**Normally**

> Eric ->(Request with session info)-> Server (Oh it's you Eric, here is
>   the response just for you)

**What are you trying to do**

> Eric ->(Request with session info)-> Server ->(Request without session
>   info)-> Server (This server doesn't know about Eric)

So to implement this correctly, if I am good at assuming what is your problem, just pass session information to the second server along with your request.

I will add more info if you tell me I am on the good track of understanding your problem.

**---UPDATE---**

You didn't explain your situation well. I am telling you this because your whole approach with the cURL may be bad decision from the start. For example, if you are trying to execute code in the same Magento codebase and that code is trapped inside some controller, perhaps you can refactor your code and encapsulate that logic inside some model and execute it directly.

But here is the example of passing session information over curl in plain php:

```
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );
```

Cookie should perhaps be called "frontend" in Magento. And I checked Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl it doesn't have any method for seting CURLOPT_COOKIE option so I suggest you go with plain curl setup. You also have an option to extend adapter and add that option by your self. Just override "_applyConfig" method.

Comment: My current state is that I don't know how to cURL the Session data from the controller to the Magento Page. I've tried session variables and Varien Object variables (getvar(), setvar()). All those can be set and used inside the controller or webpage, but the data is lost when switching between the two. I've tried the Magento curl, but could not get that to work. This is driving my nuts...

Comment: I thought about moving the code, but I needed to refresh the page anyway so all the fields were updated. If I could get information stored and retrieved in Varien objects/sessions between pages, I would think harder about moving the code. As for passing the session information, I have not found how to update Magento's session data once I get it passed over.